# What DB should i choose?

Tags: database, rdbms, robustness

I have been making desktop applications for a while now but faced some issues with my current database (SQL Server 2008) and decided to switch to a new database.

**The problem i faced with SQL Server 2008 were:-**

1. takes about 30 min to install (Express And Management)
2. installation needs the person to sit on that PC for 30 min while the setup asks for many configuration settings
3. It can only be used on Microsoft OS

**Can somebody suggest me a database that includes the following:-**

1. **Easily Deployable** - Should take less time and need least interaction for installation on CLIENT SIDE
2. **Real time Performance** - I am making a heavy multi-user ERP software so that is why the performance for the same should be great
3. **Cross Platform** - Should run on any OS

**Disclaimer** : 
*Some people might say that this question might be similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442238/what-database-should-i-choose) but its not and i also can't use SQLite because of [these](http://talks.php.net/show/sqlite_jan/4) reasons.*

Comment: Why not using mysql?

Comment: Questions asking for software recommendations are specifically off topic here.

Comment: @bub i cant use it because i have heard that it has some instability issues and also when the size of database increases its performance decreases. See this article too http://www.careerride.com/MySQL-disadvantages.aspx

Comment: @CareyGregory you may be right but can you tell me where should i post this question then?

Comment: Never heared this before. There is no instability as long as your data base design is done correctly

Comment: @bub i am just saying what i found in different articles and performance is also a must and it says poor performance scaling

Comment: @user3779606 I'm not sure but ServerFault might welcome it. Check their help section to make sure it's on topic first.

Comment: @CareyGregory how is that supposed to be in ServerFault?

Comment: @user3779606 ServerFault takes DB questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Oracle 12c (Current Version) or MySql. Oracle Database provides great features for all purpose. Both run on any OS.

Comment: does oracle has easy deployment (i doubt that)? MySQL has some instability issues and also when the size of database increases its performance decreases. See this article too careerride.com/MySQL-disadvantages.aspx

Comment: Yes, you are right MySql has some performance issues but Oracle does its best even if data is in larger amount. I myself haven't done deployment on Oracle Database before so no idea whether it is easy or not. But if you are good at SCRIPTING then this should NOT be difficult for you.